# Declare an Array without Size in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, twos-complement

I am writing a program that  converts a given bit string (up to 32-bits) into decimal assuming the input is given in unsigned magnitude and two's complement. I am reading each bit in from the user one char at a time and attempting to store it into an array, but the array doesn't have a required size. Is there a way to get the array to go through the loop without the array size being known? I also am trying to figure out a way to not use the pow and multiplication functions. I am posting my code below, if you have any ideas please

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

#define MAX_BITS 32
#define ENTER '\n'
#define NUMBER_TWO 2

int main()
{
        int unsignedMag;
        int twosComp;
        int negation[n];
        int bitStore[n];
        char enter;

        //Input from the User
        printf("Enter up to 32 bits (hit 'enter' to terminate early): ");

        //Reads the first bit as a character
        char bit = getchar();
        while (getchar != enter) {
                bit = bit - '0';
                scanf("%c", &bitStore[bit]);
                getchar();
        }

        //Terminates if user hits enter
        if (bit == enter) {
                return 0;
        }

        //Continue through code
        else {
                //Loop to calculate unsigned magnitude
                for (int i = 0; i < bitStore[i]; i++) {
                        unsignedMag = unsignedMag + (bitStore[i] * pow(NUMBER_TWO, i));
                }

                //Loop to calculate complete negation
                for (int j = 0; j < bitStore; j++) {
                        negation[j] = ~bitStore[j]
                }
                negation = negation + 1;
                for (int l = 0; l < negation; l++) {
                        twosComp = twosComp + (negation[l] * pow(NUMBER_TWO, l));
                }


        }
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: you can find the size by `size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` method - but only where the array has been defined not where it has been passed.

Answer (score 2):

> "Is there a way to get the array to go through the loop without the array size being known?"

No.  Array sizes are fixed at the point the array is declared and the size is knownable:  e.g. [@Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468564/declare-an-array-without-size-in-c-programming/52468672#comment91879041_52468564)

```
size_t size = sizeof bitStore/sizeof bitStore[0];
```

---

Instead, since code has "given bit string (up to 32-bits) ", define the array as size 32 (or 33 is a *string* is desired).
Keep track of how much of the array was assigned.

```
//int bitStore[n];
int bitStore[MAX_BITS];
int count = 0;

// char bit = getchar();
int bit = getchar(); // Use `int` to account for potentially 257 different values

//while (getchar != enter) {
while (count < MAX_BITS && (bit == '0' || bit == '1')) {
    bit = bit - '0';

    // Do not read again, instead save result. 
    //scanf("%c", &bitStore[bit]);  
    bitStore[count++] = bit;

    // getchar();
    bit = getchar();
}
```

---

> to not use the pow and multiplication functions.

Simply add or multiply by 2 via a shift.  It is unclear why OP has a goal of not using "multiplication".  I see little reason to prohibit `*`.  A good compiler will emit efficient code when the underlying multiplication is expensive as `*2` is trivial to optimize.

```
    // int unsignedMag;
    unsigned unsignedMag = 0; // initialize

    // for (int i = 0; i < bitStore[i]; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      // preferred code, yet OP wants to avoid * for unclear reasons 
      // unsignedMag = unsignedMag*2 + bitStore[i];
      unsignedMag = unsignedMag + unsignedMag + bitStore[i];
    }
```

`pow()` is good to avoid for many reasons here.  Most of all, using `double` math for an integer problem runs into precision issues with wide integers.

---

> converts a given bit string (up to 32-bits) into decimal

Note that a `bitStore[]` *array* is not needed for this task. Simply form `unsignedMag` as data is read.

Comment: So what would you use instead of pow(), I'm a little unclear on what I should be doing there as I am trying to avoid multiplication and the pow() function.

Comment: @mickeyvolmouse  `unsignedMag = unsignedMag + unsignedMag + bitStore[i];` as posted, avoids the `pow()` and multiplication.

Comment: I meant for the twos compliment. I understand how to get rid of the multiplication, but I have to do 2^l to get the decimal value of the twos complement in binary as shown in the code above

Comment: @mickeyvolmouse " have to do 2^l to get the decimal value of the twos complement" is a way to do it - yet it is not the only way.  Code can replace `pow(NUMBER_TWO, l)` with `(1LL << l)`.